# Old family videos with no audio... any hope of recovering the audio?

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, matroska, audio-conversion

I have limited experience but have used simple tools like mediainfo and ffmpeg before, though I don't usually know what is happening.

I dug up some old digital video files of family members that are no longer with us. Many of the videos seem to have have no audio on playback. I tried playing with Windows Media and VLC player. Video is fine, just no audio.

I used mediainfo on an example and this is what I get:

```
General
Unique ID                                : 66326951975176960908234508091871855207 (0x31E61B3602D2209AF5F2DC7C8FAA0267)
Complete name                            : \\bigdisk\bigdisk\data\Home Videos\Edited\Older\mom.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 2
File size                                : 43.2 MiB
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 5 983 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf54.63.104
Writing library                          : Lavf54.63.104

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3
Format settings                          : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 4 328 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 9 800 kb/s
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 (30000/1001) FPS
Standard                                 : NTSC
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Interlaced
Scan type, store method                  : Separated fields
Scan order                               : Top Field First
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.418
Stream size                              : 31.2 MiB (72%)
Default                                  : No
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : A_PCM/INT/LIT
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 536 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 11.1 MiB (26%)
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

Does that tell you anything? Is there a chance of salvaging the audio?

As [PierU suggested in the comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1742657/old-family-videos-with-no-audio-any-hope#comment2701012_1742657), I ran the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i mom.mkv -map a:0 -c:a copy -f s16le mom.raw
```

Then

```
od -t d2 mom.raw | more
```

I did so, and the output is like this:

```
0000000      6     12      5     12      1     11      5     13
0000020      6     12      2      9      5     12      6     12
0000040      3     12      3     10      6     13      3     12
0000060      3     10      5     13      5     13      3     10
0000100      3     12      6     13      4     11      3     11
0000120      4     12      4     12      3     10      3     11
0000140      6     13      4     10      2     11      6     13
0000160      4     12      3     10      5     12      5     13
0000200      3      9      4     12      5     14      4     10
0000220      3     12      5     13      4     10      2     10
0000240      5     12      4     11      3      9      5     12
0000260      5     12      4     10      2     10      4     12
0000300      6     13      3     10      4     12      5     11
0000320      3      9      3     10      5     14      4     12
0000340      3     10      3     12      4     11      3      9
0000360      4     11      5     13      2      9      2     10
0000400      5     13      5     12      3      9      4     11
0000420      5     13      1      9      3     11      5     12
0000440      3     10      2     10      5     13      3     10
0000460      1      9      6     14      4     12      2      8
0000500      3     11      5     12      2      9      3     11
0000520      5     13      3     10      1      8      4     12
0000540      4     11      3     10      4     12      5     12
```

Comment: Sorry to hear you're having troubles with this. Make sure you have multiple backup copies of all these files stored so you can mess around with them. I would edit your question and add the "ffmpeg" tag in addition to "audio" and "audio-conversion". The ffmpeg community have extensive knowledge on matters concerning file formats and converting tasks.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll do that.

Comment: The audio track is present, but maybe completely muted... Do you have access to Linux command line tools ? Try first extracting the audio stream: `ffmpeg -i mom.mkv -map a:0 -c:a copy -f s16le mom.raw`. Then `od -t d2 mom.raw | more`: If you see only zeros except in the first column, then it's bad...

Comment: @PierU I suggested ffmpeg community get involved here but I don't believe bcsteeve has ffmpeg installed yet. He may need help with that.

Comment: I do have ffmpeg :). I said so in my original question.  I just don't have the understanding beyond trying specific commands.  @PierU provided and I haven't had an opportunity to try it yet.  Ty both for the help

Comment: @PierU I've run the commands you suggested and edited my question to include the output.

Comment: From what you are showing it looks like the audio is there and seems 100% fine. So to me this seems like a playback issue. A PCM audio file is the most basic audio file out there and is common on Windows. Have you tried rebooting your PC and attempting to play the video again? Or maybe put the video on a USB flash drive and playing it on another system? I honestly believe you might just have the audio turned down in some way. It makes no sense that a basic PCM audio stream would not be playing. If you are using VLC check the audio menu item and see if the audio stream is even set to playback.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 thanks, but there are other files in the same folder that play just fine (video and audio) so I don't think it is simply a matter of my system audio being silent.

I used ffmpeg to jack the audio way up and all I get is noise.  I think it might be an issue with the source video when it was transferred to digital.  Because you're right, it appears there's a stream there.

Comment: Some audio seems to be present, but with extremely low volume: values around 10, for a maximum of +/-32768 in 16 bits. That -70dB... And no negative value, which is not expected... If the values are similar all along the file this is not normal (and this may be just some electronic noise during recording, with a muted microphone for some reason). Try to boost the volume by adding `-filter:a "volume=60dB"` to the ffmpeg command line. You may output a proper audio file and listen to it with VLC: `ffmpeg -i mom.mkv -map a:0 -filter:a "volume=60dB" -c:a pcm_s16le mom.wav`.

Comment: (beware of the volume on your playback system after a 60dB boost...). Alternatively you may load your initial file in Audacity, which will show you what the audio track looks really like and will allow to interactively apply amplification or other processing.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you have already tested a volume boost... If all what you hear looks like noise, it confirms that there has been something wrong in the process. I understand that these files have been converted from an analog source? I guess that you no longer have them? I also understand that some of your videos have some proper audio: do they show any difference when opened with Mediainfo ?

Comment: I will give it a little more attention and try audacity (thank you, I hadn't thought of that), but I now think I'm dealing with files that have no audio from the source.  These were converted from analog, which were subsequently lost in a house fire.  At least we have some that work, and we have the video.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The comments were helpful, especially [the comments by PierU](https://superuser.com/questions/1742657/old-family-videos-with-no-audio-any-hope-of-recovering-the-audio#comment2701012_1742657).

Unfortunately, the source files only contain electronic noise.  Either the originals never had audio (user error, defective mic, etc) or some difficulty occurred when converting to digital, years ago.  The originals are lost.

At least the family has the video, and there are others remaining with audio.

I very much thank this community for being there for me with this.

Comment: Thanks for posting this as an answer here. I was going to suggest you do so but you already have done so! At least now there is confirmation that an audio track exists; but of course nothing was recorded. Best of thoughts to you and your family.

Comment: You might consider adding a music track. Even the old silent films had music.

Comment: @MDeBusk Music is not the same as actual live audio of people speaking.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 No, it's not the same, and I'm not suggesting the OP replace live audio of people speaking with music. The OP has plainly said that there is no live audio of people speaking. I'm suggesting replacing what the OP called "noise" with music.

Comment: @MDeBusk, I very much appreciated the suggestion and that's exactly what I did.  Thank you.

Comment: @bcsteeve And now you've got me wondering whatever happened to all the old 8mm film my father's brother had of my grandparents. My paternal grandfather died before I was born. I wouldn't mind seeing those old home movies again. It's been decades.